# Перемещение объекта мышкой, проверка выхода объекта за границу

Tags: алгоритм

Есть приложение, в котором пользователь может перемещать объекты на поле курсором мышкой - зажимает левую кнопку на объекте и горизонтально его перемещает. Поле представляет собой плоскость, по горизонтали располагается ось времени, вертикальная ось не важна. Также на поле есть временные границы, за которые объект не должен выходить. Объект содержит в себе дату его начала и дату окончания. Временная граница - это объект с некоторой датой. Проблема в том, что при резком движении мыши случается ситуация, когда дельта перемещения бывает очень большой, и условие остановки перемещения отрабатывает, когда объект частично пересек границу. Подскажите идею, как можно в этой ситуации останавливать объект вплотную к границе, что бы он ее никак не пересекал.